# Jasmine failing to instantiate Angular module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Okay, so Im trying to implement unit tests for an AngularJS project using Jasmine 2.2.0 - and I am not able to get a basic example test working for a controller.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code for the controller (the simplest one I have):

```
angular.module('app.alerts')
    .controller('AlertCtrl', AlertCtrl);

AlertCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'AlertService'];

function AlertCtrl($scope, AlertService) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.closeAlert = function(index) {
        AlertService.closeAlert(index);
    }

    vm.getAlertList = function() {
        return AlertService.getAlertList();
    }
}
```

And here is the spec file I am trying to run:

```
describe('myApp', function() {
    describe('controller', function() {

        var scope, controller;
        var mockAlertService = {      // simple mock service
            closeAlert: function(e) {
                console.log('close');
            },
            getAlertList: function() {
                return [];
            }
        }    

        beforeEach(function() {
            angular.mock.module('app.alert');
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('AlertCtrl as alertctrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                AlertService: mockAlertService
            });
        }));

        it('should work: ', function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the test I get the following error message:

```
Error: [$inject:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.alert due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'app.alert' is not available! You either misspelled
the module name or forgot to load it.
```

It seems that the injector doesn't know about the app.alert module, which means its not being properly mocked?  Im including the angular-mocks.js file in my SpecRunner.html file.  Can anybody see what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you misspelled `app.alert` and `app.alerts`:

```
angular.module('app.alerts')
    .controller('AlertCtrl', AlertCtrl);
```

and

```
angular.mock.module('app.alert');
```

Comment: ...aaaand Im dumb.  Thanks.